# Different Results Between R and Sudaan with Complex Survey Design

Tags: r, survey

I am currently using the Public Access version of the Survey of State Inmates in Correctional Facilities 2004 dataset and I am trying to use their survey weights, which uses jackknife replicate weights with multipliers.

I am obtaining results that are different from the ones presented in their codebook and in their BJS reports. I believe it may have something to do with my code. I am looking for a standard error of 0.82 and am receiving a standard error of 0.89. Is that due to differences in programs or due to a problem with my code?

I am using the complete sample that they are presenting in the codebook.

I have tried it in Stata as well as the R code marked below. I have tried variants of this code too (i.e., no MSE option in the code), to no avail.

R-Code

```
design.rw2 <- svrepdesign(repweights ="v[1-2888]", weights = 
completerecords$weight2, data = completerecords, type = "JK1", scale=1,
 rscales=c(rep(0.8, 5), rep(0.9, 10), rep(0.93333, 15),
rep(0.875, 8),rep(0.75, 4), rep(0.6667, 3),rep(0.8889, 9), rep(0, 1)), 
combined.weights=TRUE, mse=TRUE)
```

Example SUDAAN code they have is:

```
proc crosstab data=spi04_state design=jackknife;
 weight weight2;
 jackwgts v2833 – v2887;
 jackmult 5*0.8 10*0.9 15*0.93333 8*0.8750 4*0.75 3*0.6667 9*0.8889 1*0;
 class  v2602 / nofreq; * veteran status;
 tables v2602;
 output rowper serow nsum wsum sewgt / filename=estimates_state_female
 filetype=sas replace;
run;
```

Thank you!

Andrew

Comment: hi, could you edit your question to include the comparable SUDAAN code?  `[1-2888]` seems odd. do you want `[1-3]`?  when you type `design.rw2` does the design tell you the correct number of replicate weights?

Comment: I actually don't have the comparable SUDAAN code. I am comparing my results to the official BJS reports and the results found in the codebook, which use SUDAAN. The 1-2888 is because it is not accepting 2833 (the beginning of the replicate weights). There are no variables from 1 to 2832. When I type in design.rw2, all the columns for the replicate weights show.

Comment: I have actually found example SUDAAN code, and have added it to the original posting.

Comment: hi, might just want `v28` then, it's a string match. other things to check might be (1) `"JKn"` instead of `"JK1"` (2) where is `weight2` from?  docs say `v2832`  (3) is the PUF different from the BLS file?  some public data sets will not match exactly because the internal data set differs slightly.  if they used taylor series for those published SEs, that's another reason for not matching..

Comment: I renamed v2832 to weight2 in order to do that fix with 1-2887. Your solution worked for that, by the way. That is one possibility -- that the data files differ slightly. The point estimates are similar, but because they round there is no telling whether it is exactly the same. When I try JKn, the results are the same as when I do JK1. I am wondering whether it is not reading the r-scales properly. They show up when I do ```design.rw2```. So maybe that is not it either.

Comment: Your last point, may be true as well. Since they are using the Restricted Access datafile (I am assuming), they have access to the primary sampling units and the strata information. Meaning, they can model it directly and do not need to rely on jackknife replication weights. Could that be the difference?

Comment: hi, if the document you're trying to match used taylor series linearization and you only have replicate weights, you won't be able to match exactly

Comment: That is probably it then. The numbers I am trying to match are likely using that since they have that extra information available. My estimates are not that far off from theirs, I guess. I will double check with the authors, however. Thank you so much. If you respond with a general summary or something as an answer, I will mark this as solved.